Xubuntu 22.04 - changing default terminal to Kitty breaking launcher
My default terminal has been Xfce Terminal.
I have a Panel launcher that runs the simple command:-
thunar /home/me/Desktop/games
(All via GUI) The option is set to "Run in Terminal" and I've tried with and without "use Startup Notification". Working directory is blank.
If I change the default terminal editor from Xfce Terminal to XTerminal, it works as normal. But if I change it to Kitty, it gives the error:-
Failed to launch child: thunar /home/me/Desktop/games
With error: No such file or directory
Press Enter to exit.
Some other shell scripts set to "Open in Terminal" also failed - their errors were similar but appeared in the UI so I guess the different wording is generated by Xfce rather than Kitty.
Failed to execute child
Failed to execute child process "home/me/Desktop/games": failed to execve: No such file or directory
Of course the directory is still where it's supposed to be and opens in any instances of Thunar that were left open. So I wondered if it is expecting the default Terminal Emulator to be located in a particular directory. But it seems they are both installed to the same place:-
which kitty
/usr/bin/kitty
which xfce4-terminal
/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
Lastly, opening Kitty and then running "thunar /home/me/Desktop/games" works fine.
So I wonder if the way the UI launcher allows, or handles a blank working directory is OK for xfce terminal but not Kitty.
Is there an easy fix for this - i.e. easy without manually editing lots of launchers?
